# Problem with Z shell and Bash shell on my mac os terminal

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I got a problem with my computer shells . I was using zsh shell . then after installing flutter , i can run basic command like `cd`,`cat`,`nano` .. in my terminal and i got errors like :

```
    nano ~/.bash_profile
    zsh: command not found: nano
```

Note that nano command was working very well, how could i solve it ?

so here is my .bash_profile content:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export PATH="/Users/users/Downloads/flutter/bin:$PATH"
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.12.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

And here is my .zshrc content :

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

Comment: Set a valid PATH, or at least remove whatever you added to your dotfiles that's setting a bad one. Also, note that SO is only for questions about *writing software*.

Comment: So -- what changes to your dotfiles did you make while installing flutter? Be specific.

Comment: i've just added PATH to flutter SKD , the JAVA_HOME path, then install cocoapod . But i was doing all of that in the .bash_profile then i have done the same in the zshrc file since my shell is Z shell . Now i cant even open these files with nano

Comment: If when "adding" a new PATH entry you failed to preserve the old ones, that explains this problem. You need to show us the code you used if you want anyone to be able to say what's wrong with it.

Comment: And keep in mind that bash and zsh are two different shells; not all code that works for one is expected to work in the other.

Comment: Anyhow, until you fix this you can open nano by specifying the absolute path to its executable. That's typically `/usr/bin/nano`.

Comment: I ve just edit my post . here are all my files bash_profile and .zshrc contents

Comment: In both files ?

Comment: Remove in both files `export PATH="/Users/users/Downloads/flutter/bin"`, then you should be good to go.

Comment: It done but now i got this : source ~/.bash_profile
/Users/users/.rvm/scripts/rvm:12: command not found: uname
/Users/users/.rvm/scripts/rvm:29: command not found: ps

Comment: no , i have just enter the code : source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Start a new Terminal.

Comment: ok  i have some edits in both files

Comment: when i start a new terminal and run : flutter doctor , i got : zsh: command not found: flutter

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: add the output of `echo $PATH` to the question.

Comment: `declare -p PATH` will also work (in bash) to print your current path so you can see what's wrong.

Comment: (and as others have said -- you can't just source the file here; that'll apply _new_ changes but it won't undo incorrect _older_ changes, so you need to start a new terminal window, or a new tab in an existing terminal, between tests)

Comment: In particular, note that using the corrected line `export PATH="/Users/users/Downloads/flutter/bin:$PATH` doesn't fix the problem previously created by running `export PATH="/Users/users/Downloads/flutter/bin"` -- you need to start a new terminal window (or explicitly set a correct PATH) to make that problem go away.

Comment: So, what actually is the value of your PATH variable, at the time you are invoking `nano`?

Comment: Also, please don't tag this bash **and** zsh, and focus on a single shell. Maybe if you find the problem in one - say: bash -, you will be able to figure out the solution for the other one as well.

Answer (score -1):

I am not having your OS.
I tried the same using cygwin at windows.
Initially I was not having nano.

1. installed nano.exe at windows:
   setup-x86_64.exe --no-admin
2. 

open bash.exe
3)

```
vi ~/.zshrc
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
#/cygdrive/c/Users/myusername/cygwin_x86_64/lib/zsh/5.8/zsh/zle.dll file is present
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/cygdrive/c/Users/MyWindowsUserName/cygwin_x86_64/lib/zsh/5.8
export PS1=$'\033[36m%n\033[m@\033[32m%m:\033[33;1m%d\033[m
\$ '
if [ "" = "$count" ]
then
        cd
        count=$?
fi
```

3. 

```
$ cat ~/.zenv
export MODULE_PATH=/cygdrive/c/Users/myusername/cygwin_x86_64/lib/zsh/5.8:$MODULE_PATH
FPATH=$HOME/opt/software/zsh/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion:$FPATH
```

4. inside bash shell:

```
$ which nano
/usr/bin/nano
$ /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/where.exe nano.exe
C:\Users\myserusername\cygwin\bin\nano.exe
$ zsh
$ which nano
/usr/bin/nano
$ nano ~/.zshrc
Ctrlx
```

Hence install all dependencies including LD_LIBRARY_PATH/... environment variables related to zsh.

> > /... environment variables related to zsh
> > ... related to OS/environment.

Comment: Those dependencies are only for Cygwin on Windows; they are not correct for MacOS.

Comment: (in particular, the OP does not need LD_LIBRARY_PATH -- the copy of zsh they have is included by their OS vendor; no overridden libraries are needed to make it work -- and the edit history of the question shows us very clearly their problem, caused by overriding rather than prepending to PATH; the comment history further shows us that they didn't know they needed to start a new terminal window to undo that mistake, so even when they fixed it the problem was still present in their already-active terminal session).